# where and how to link html file,css file,javascript file and jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, jsp

i have CSS file in one folder,html file in one folder,javascript  in one folder. where shoul i link these files and how?whether in html or jsp page.please let me know.. even after giving a link like
 where CSS is my folder.
how a proper aggregation is needed in in eclipse considering the industry standards ?

Comment: Are you referring to linking files on a web server or from your personal machine?

Answer (score 2):

You link the files on your html page in the head of the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
        <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    ...
```

Some people recommend linking javascript at the end of the document (just before the closing body tag) so that the visible elements can be rendered first before the javascript is parsed.

Just to clarify, css must be in the head; javascript can be anywhere and possibly/probably optimal at the end.

Answer (score 0):

use link element to link various resources to your page like: CSS files, a favorite icon ...
check out this [video demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_link_tag.php)

and script tag (as shown above by Crazysheep) to link scripts